# Constraints in UITableViewCell not being calculated

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I have the following cell with constraints being setup programmatically:

```
class RadioButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

static let identifier = "RadioButtonCell"

let radioButton = RadioButton()
let labelTitle = UILabel()

private var didUpdateConstraints = false

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupSubViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func setupSubViews() {
    radioButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    labelTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(radioButton)
    contentView.addSubview(labelTitle)
}

override func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()
    if !didUpdateConstraints {
        radioButton.anchor(leading: contentView.leadingAnchor, padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: Constants.UI.defaultMarginX2, bottom: 0, right: 0))
        radioButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        labelTitle.anchor(leading: radioButton.trailingAnchor, padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: Constants.UI.defaultMarginX2, bottom: 0, right: 0))
        labelTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        didUpdateConstraints = true
    }
  }
}
```

The `anchor` method is just a helper method to add constraints. The constraints are setup correctly (no issues with Autolayout).

Then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I create the cell like so:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RadioButtonCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? RadioButtonCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
radtioButtonController.addButton(cell.radioButton)
cell.labelTitle.text = "test"
return cell
```

This creates me the following layout in the tableView (which is obviously wrong):
[image]

If I move the setup of the constraints to the `setupSubViews()` method, the layout is correct:

```
class RadioButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

static let identifier = "RadioButtonCell"

let radioButton = RadioButton()
let labelTitle = UILabel()

private var didUpdateConstraints = false

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupSubViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func setupSubViews() {
    radioButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    labelTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(radioButton)
    contentView.addSubview(labelTitle)
    radioButton.anchor(leading: contentView.leadingAnchor, padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: Constants.UI.defaultMarginX2, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    radioButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    labelTitle.anchor(leading: radioButton.trailingAnchor, padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: Constants.UI.defaultMarginX2, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    labelTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
 }
}
```

[image]

Why is this like that? I thought we should setup constraint in the `updateConstraints` method...

Thank you for an answer :)

**Edit** I found out, that it works with `updateConstraints` when I call `cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` or `cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Why do we need to tell the cell to calculate the constraints again? We do not need to do that when adding the constraints with IB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your first example you haven't just added the constraints to your UI elements in the `init`. You just set up your sub views.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupSubViews()
    // No explicit constraint setup happened
}
```

To setup your constraints you've overridden the `override func updateConstraints() { ... }` method. Let's take a look at the [official documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622512-updateconstraints).

> In short, your override will be in effect when you notify the system that you need constraints' update. As a result you need to explicitly inform the system by invoking **`setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`** or **`updateConstraintsIfNeeded()`**.

---

---

Let's look at your second example. You embedded the constraints setup inside your `private func setupSubViews(){ ... }`. So at the time this function gets called, your constraints are ready to be applied. No system call needed.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Followup question: I encountered views where I did not need to explicitly call setNeedsUpdateConstraints() or updateConstraintsIfNeeded() when setting up the constraints in updateConstraints(). In which situation this might occur?

Comment: Okay, if you encountered such scenario then somehow, somewhere any of the `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` or `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` is invoked. Typically this is done from the `setup...` methods like `self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`.